# AWS SSL Certificate renewal issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, certificate

I am trying to renew a certificate in AWS Certificate Manager when I put the Certificate body and the Certificate private key, I receive the following error:

"Sorry! New certificate is missing one or more Extended Key Usages supported by the currently imported certificate"

We have processed the certificate renewal from a third party, I have created a certificate request in IIS  then completed the certificate request and exported the crt and key files which I am trying to put to AWS.
I am not sure if I am missing anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting similar error while doing certificate reimport to AWS Certificate Manager.

The reason I found for this error is,

In the old certificate there are two extended key usages - **TLS_WEB_SERVER_AUTHENTICATION **and** TLS_WEB_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION**

However, in the new certificate, there is only one extended key usage - **TLS Web Server Authentication**

As per following AWS Document, we can add new Extended Key Usage extensions but existing extension values cannot be removed.

**https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-reimport.html**

Thus, to resolve this issue we have two option available.

**Option 1:** We can consider re-importing the certificate and make sure it includes all the KeyUsage/ExtendedkeyUsage attribute as the old certificate.

**Option 2:** Alternative is to import the certificate as a new one instead. After this, we would have to manually update the cloudfront/ELB to use this newly imported certificate.

I tried **Option 1** and it resolved the issue.

Other necessary details, we must have to look into while uploading the certificate.

-> New certificate details we should have,

**1. Certificate Body
2. Certificate Private Key
3. Certificate Chain (Optional)**

Note: If you are renewing certificate using AWS CLI, make sure above details must be in .pem format

-> Command to convert Private Key to Private RSA,

**openssl rsa -in private.key -out private_rsa.key**